# Using nginx file upload when using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, file-upload, nginx, tornado, gridfs

Users says that Tornado is bad for file upload since it uses memory, so they use Nginx, but my question, is:

What if the files are not stored in the normal system, but in MongoDB (GridFS), then, Nginx will be useless?

Comment: You cna make a c extension for save the callback of a multipart upload to gridfs, but I know of no extension that will do this for you

Comment: so right now we can say that without extension, when using gridfs, nginx file upload is useless?

Comment: Not totally, I mean it is still very scalable if you get one that writes each part out to a file and releases the worker

Comment: so then i have to write an extension from scratche?

Comment: Yes, currently, there might be one lurking but a quick search didn't find anything

Comment: yes, this is sad, because even the ngnix-gridfs got like 'deprecated' by its developpers, so i think i will stuck with the normal tornado upload, or make a cron that upload the file from a folder to gridfs and then delete them?